# Compositing versus video sequence editor for combining video file with own animation

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

I need to make a video where I take a movie file and add some of my own blender animation to it. Last time I did this I did the whole thing as a standard blender animation, with a "screen" object in my scene which had a video texture. I realise this is not optimal and that there are at least two better ways to do this: compositing or using the video sequence editor. I have not used either. My question is, what are the pluses and minuses of each of these ways? Can one say that either is easier than the other for a novice to pick up?

Comment: I also would use the compositor for it, but it is more easy in video sequence editor. But like Mike Pan wrote you have more possibilities in compositor. For a high quality-merge you will need the compositor for a simple overlay the sequnce editor is ok. hope it helps... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence editor is designed for non-linear editing. While it has some basic comp features to layer images on top of each other, you do not have the level of control that you get with the compositor. For anything but a trivial overlay, I highly suggest using the compositor for the task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a useful answer! Not enough rep to upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use both. The output of the compositor is available as the "Scene Strip" of the video sequence editor, provided they are both enabled in the render tab (which they are by default).